# Using distinct in case condition sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to use distinct in the case statement in sql ?

For example -

```
CASE WHEN col1 = 'XYZ' and DISTINCT(col1,col2)
THEN 'Do_This'
ELSE 'Do_That'
END
```

Unfortunately the usage of DISTINCT inside the case statement as above throws an error.

I'm using postgres/redshift sql.

Comment: what's your goal for that query?

Comment: That query does not make any sense

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* that simply returns a *scalar* value. It cannot be used for control flow like in procedural languages. Also, `DISTINCT` cannot be used as a predicate. When used in a `SELECT` statement `DISTINCT` filters out duplicate rows.

Comment: show a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: if you get an error, provide the errormsg please. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First of all your objective is not clear but from your query my assumption is as you want to DO_This or Do_That depending on col1 values as 'XYZ' with group by col 1, col2.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN COL1 = 'XYZ'
THEN 'DO_THIS'
ELSE 'DO_THAT'
END
FROM 
(
SELECT 
COL1, COL2
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY COL1, COL2
)
```